# how to get output in the below format from the following json data using jaql script

Tags: json, jjaql

I am doing a facebook analysis project using jaql, from the below json data. 
i need to get the name of the of the page when i give an id.
for example, if i give id: '327945414026898'then i should get name: 'first name'. i have tried the following command but i am not getting any output

```
data1[0] -> filter  $.likes.data[*].id =='327945414026898'
```

but did not get any out put

the Json Data :

```
[{
id: '1071142589616282',
name: 'kps',
likes: {
    data: [{
            name: 'first_name',
            id: '327945414026898',
            created_time: '2018-03-27T20:41:50+0000'
        },
        {
            name: 'second name',
            id: '180392125340045',
            created_time: '2010-11-22T06:36:33+0000'
        },
        {
            name: 'third name',
            id: '149186111778540',
            created_time: '2010-10-07T11:25:22+0000'
        }

    ]
}
}]
```

Comment: Unclear why this was tagged with Hadoop... Which, if you were using, then you wouldn't be using jjaql, rather Spark, Hive, or Pig